# What is the significance of the Ouija scene?

Tags: red-rose

Somewhere near the middle of the series *Red Rose*, we see a flashback to 2013 or so, in which some people, including some of the parents of the protagonists, do a Ouija ritual that they rather ominously leave improperly concluded. This seems designed to set up a supernatural element to the plot.

However, every element of the show points to the titular application being completely mundane. Everything that it does is theoretically possible with the right knowledge and resources, there are completely normal (if psychopathic) people behind it, and even most or all of the "mysterious suicides" are simply outright pedestrian murders interpreted as suicide because of social media posts and so forth. Admittedly, the Gardener does look a bit like death warmed over, but there is little to suggest that she is anything more than a human being.

What, then, is the meaning of the scene with the Ouija board?

Comment: From what I can tell it was absolutely pointless and just a red herring.

Comment: I found this post with the same question. Why oh why did that scene exist!? Really seems like it was just to make you think red rose was supernatural, just hackers though.